# Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime in a Stored Procedure from code

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, oledb

I'm getting the following error when calling a stored procedure from C#.

the parameters are defined in the code as:

```
 if (repRIS.Length > 0)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@repRIS", repRIS);
 else
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@repRIS", DBNull.Value);
  command.Parameters.Add("@invDt", OleDbType.Date).Value = invDate;
```

I have commented out everything out of the stored procedure and now only have the following:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SearchDates]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
     @invDt datetime,
     @repRIS varchar(10) ,

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

select this, that, and, the, other from myTableName ird
where
     ird.RIS = COALESCE(@repRIS, ird.RIS) 
     and ird.InventoryDate = @invDt
END
```

The InventoryDate is of type DateTime in the database.

when I run the SP from the SQL MS it produces results with no issues, however, when using the application to call it, I get the following error message

> Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime

I've noticed that it started happening after I switched from SQLConnection to OLEDBConnection. I am yet to confirm this. (i had to switch to comply with how the rest of the application was written before me)

UPDATE:
when I am putting in the value of 9/30/2018 in the textbox, it is getting passed into the stored procedure as: `{9/30/2018 12:00:00 AM}` after converting to datetime (code above)

Comment: Use SQL Server Profiler to see how your application sends @invDt

Comment: What is the datatype of `invDate`?   How is it populated?   What is it populated with when the error occurs?

Comment: it's populated with DateTime.MinValue {1/1/0001 12;00:00 AM}

Comment: You can have one of three issues 1) The value in database could be null.  The c# DateTime object does not take a null value 2) The DataTime in database could be a string and c# is expecting a DateTime object 3)  You are using a SQL Server.  Why an oledb DataTime?  Should be SqlDbType.DateTime (or SqlDbType.DateTime2).

Comment: OLEDB has no problems. It's the most common way to connect to SQL Server after all. The error is explicit, there was an attempt to mix strings and dates. Either `invDate` is a `String` or `InventoryDate` is `nvarchar`

Comment: The problem could be that ird.RIS is a datetime field and the error is here.  ird.RIS = COALESCE(@repRIS, ird.RIS)

Comment: @MadamZuZu to sum it up, post enough code to diagnose the problem. Post the table schema and the variable definitions. Right now people have to guess

Comment: Can you try: var invDate2 = Convert.ToDateTime(invDate.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));   and pass invDate2 to your stored procedure ?

Comment: Not sure about the syntax, if my above comment does not work please try: var invDate2 = DateTime.Parse (invDate.ToString(), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Comment: BTW `ird.RIS = COALESCE(@repRIS, ird.RIS) ` is a bad idea. Such `catch-all` parameters invariably result in bad performance. The query optimizer will generate and cache an execution plan based on the values used the first time it runs. That execution plan may not use eg indexes that cover `ird.RIS` if that first value is `NULL`. On the other hand, involving those indexes will be wasteful if `ird.RIS` isn't needed

Comment: @ErayBalkanli that's a meaningles line of code. `DateTime` has no format, it's a binary value just like ints and decimals. That line will only *cause* problems - it will only work in the US as `invDate.ToString()` uses the current locale

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using OleDb one should always remember that the parameters are not passed according to their names but in the exact order in which they are added to the Parameters collection.

In your code you add first the @repRIS and this is the first parameter passed to the SP. But the SP expects a date for the first parameter and you get the exception

You need to change the order of the insertion in the Parameters collection or switch the declaration order of the parameters in the SP

```
command.Parameters.Add("@invDt", OleDbType.Date).Value = invDate;     
if (repRIS.Length > 0)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@repRIS", repRIS);
else
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@repRIS", DBNull.Value);
```

And another thing to do is to look at this article [Can we stop using AddWithValue already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: i had no idea the order was important! thank you! i'm going to validate the rest of the SP right now, but i think this is it! thank you again!

Comment: If you used Profiler, you could see that your parameters are passing in other order. And if it was any other issue, you could see what exactly code your app was sending

Answer (score 0):

I would say that Min Date does not work in SQL from C# since min C# Datetime and the one supported by SQL are different.

Use :

```
System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.MinValue.Value
```

instead the Min offered by C# Datetime.
This should work

Comment: You *assume* that `datetime` is used insteaf of eg `datetime2`. In this case though, the OP isn't using MinValue at all.

Comment: I am not assuming nothing, look the stored procedure, please.

Comment: The minimum date value isn't used anywhere

Comment: He said that on the comments.